# PHP Regex to Match This:

Tags: php, regex

```
[foreach:regex]
    [r_hello]
[/foreach]
```

Trying to match the above: `regex` (word between `:` and `]`) will be `$1` and anything between `[foreach:regex]` and `[/foreach]` will be `$2`.

So far I have this: `/\[foreach:(.*)\](.*)\[\/foreach\]/s`

But I'm getting this error: `Notice: Undefined index: regex] [r_hello`

Comment: Is the spaces leading to `[r_hello]` a quantity of space characters or is it a tab character?

Comment: Tab character, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
/\[foreach:([^\]]*)\]\s*\[([^\]]*)\]\s*\[\/foreach\]/s
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7av-ypa

The problems were:

1. You were greedy matching one or more of any character, which can be avoided here
2. You weren't accounting for the whitespace (newlines and tabs)
3. You weren't accounting for the square brackets arounf the central item.

Comment: No match. Thanks for the attempt though.

Comment: Thanks so much! Accepting your answer now. :)